# Why does scrollview in pager not scroll in Android 4.1.2 API 16, but works on the rest?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with a `TextView` that scrolls a text inside a `ViewPager`. My app supports minimum API 8. Everything works until I tests it on Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2 API 16. The text in the `ScrollView` won't scroll. When I Google it, one suggestion is the Swype keyboard, but when I run it on the emulater with stock Android 4.1.2, the problem is still there. Then I try to check if it is working on different API's and I have checked and it works on those API: 10, 13, 15, 17 and 19. It scrolls slow on API <= 15, but it scrolls. On API 16 it does not scroll. On API >= 17 it scrolls normal (slow and fast).

Why does this work on all API except 16?

This is my `ScreenSlidePageFragment.java`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            getString(R.string.title_template_step) + (mPageNumber + 1));

    // Set background image and text (mPageNumber start with 0)
    switch (mPageNumber + 1) {
        case 1:
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_slides).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_1);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textScroll)).setText(getString(R.string.page1));
            break;
        case 2:
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_slides).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_2);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textScroll)).setText(getString(R.string.page2));
            break;
        case 3:
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_slides).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_3);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textScroll)).setText(getString(R.string.page3));
            break;
        case 4:
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_slides).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_4);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textScroll)).setText(getString(R.string.page4));
            break;
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

And this is the .xml file for this fragment

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view_slides"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- content. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!-- This is the text which are scrolled -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewText"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textScroll"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/day"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />


    </ScrollView>

    <!-- This text shows the page number -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scrolling the `ScrollView` instead of the `TextView`, like:

```
ScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Or

```
ScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Also, change your XML layout to:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- This is the text which are scrolled -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewText"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <TextView
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textScroll"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/day"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- This text shows the page number -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Note: I have removed the outermost `ScrollView` unless there's more codes you haven't posted. Otherwise, the outermost `ScrollView` is redundant. And, if it still does not work, then remove `android:fillViewport="true"` from the `ScrollView`.

Recommendation: Unless you really need it, I would use a `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout`, instead of a `FrameLayout`.

**IMPORTANT**: You cannot have two `ScrollView` together in one layout - it will not work across all API levels.

Comment: Sorry if I have been not clear enough. I can post the working code for all API except APi 16.

Comment: If you have the `TextView` included / embedded in a `ScrollView`, then use my methods above to scroll the `TextView`. Otherwise, edit your post to include your XML codes so I can see how you've constructed your `TextView` and `ScrollView`. Also, when you say _"work for all API except 16"_, have you tested on different Android devices from different manufacturers and/or Android AVDs?

Comment: I have tested on HTC with Android 3.1, Asus Android 4.4, Asus Android 4.2, Samsung Android 4.1.2 (not working), AVD with API 10, 15, 16 (not working), 17, 19.

Comment: @espy: Modified my answer to include a modified version of the XML layout you've posted.

Comment: The outermost `ScrollView` is used by the `ViewPager` as in this example [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#fragment) which I used. Question then, do the `ViewPager`need `ScrollView` or can I use `RelativeLayout` instead?

Comment: If you wrapped a `ScrollView` around the `ViewPager`, then you need to add `android:fillViewport="true"` to this `ScrollView`. In choosing between a `ScrollView` and a `RelativeLayout` - this is your UI decision - and I can't see visually what you're trying to do. Also, you cannot have two `ScrollView` together in one layout - it will not work across all API levels, as you have just found out.

Comment: You found it. Two `ScrollView` inside each other did not work for all API and slowed it down on earlier API's. Thank you so much!

Comment: @espy: Glad I could help. I have updated my answer to include the point about having two `ScrollView` together in one layout so others who will read your post in the future will know that this is the main problem you had with your post.